# Programmatically create stack view

Tags: swift, uistackview, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create a date component by using a stack view programmatically. If user enters wrong date an error label will display message accordingly.Its working fine if I create it through storyboard, but when I use my programmatically created component which has added all elements in a stack view. I am not able to see error label. 
I verified the autolayout I've added in storyboard and in my component class, both look similar. Here is code for my component.

```
        class CustomDateView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Variable
    private let dayTextField: UITextField = {
        let inputField = UITextField()
        inputField.borderStyle = .none
        inputField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        inputField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        inputField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        inputField.textAlignment = .center
        inputField.tag = 0
        inputField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return inputField
    }()

    private let monthTextField: UITextField = {
        let inputField = UITextField()
        inputField.borderStyle = .none
        inputField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        inputField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        inputField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        inputField.textAlignment = .center
        inputField.tag = 1
        inputField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return inputField
    }()

    private let yearTextField: UITextField = {
        let inputField = UITextField()
        inputField.borderStyle = .none
        inputField.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        inputField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        inputField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        inputField.textAlignment = .center
        inputField.tag = 2
        inputField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return inputField
    }()

    private let errorLabel: UILabel = {
        let errorLabel = UILabel()
        errorLabel.textColor = .red
        errorLabel.textAlignment = .center
        errorLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        errorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return errorLabel
    }()

    private let monthSeparator: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private let yearSeparator: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private let horizontalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.spacing = 16.0
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()

    private let verticalStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stackView.spacing = 8.0
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return stackView
    }()


    // MARK: - Initialisers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Functions
    private func setup() {
        self.horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.dayTextField)
        self.horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.monthSeparator)
        self.horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.monthTextField)
        self.horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.yearSeparator)
        self.horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.yearTextField)
        self.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.horizontalStackView)
        self.verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.errorLabel)
        self.addSubview(self.verticalStackView)

        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let selfType = type(of: self)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.dayTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 48.0),
            self.dayTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62.0),
            self.monthTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 62.0),
            self.monthSeparator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14.0),
            self.yearSeparator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 14.0)
            ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.verticalStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            self.verticalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.verticalStackView.bottomAnchor),
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.verticalStackView.trailingAnchor)
            ])
        } 
}
```

It render view correctly but after setting error label stack view won't grow to display the text.I have given fixed width to my separators and textfield's cause I want them to be of that exact width and height.
Is there any mistakes I'm making while applying autolayout in here.

Comment: Is the error label visible if you give it a default text, when it's created?

Comment: @andlin I just checked my code and found out that when I set numberOfLines of label to property to 0 error message is not displayed. Isn't it strange.?

Comment: I figured it out why it was not working. It has to do with distribution property of vertical stackView. I set it to fillProportionally.It should be fill instead of that.